# I have South Africa refugee passport. I am Eritrean. Can I travel to Greece without a visa?

Tags: schengen-visas, south-africa, refugees, eritrean-citizens

I need to visit Greek with a South African refugee document. Can I travel without a visa?

Answer (score 0):

Using the passport of the country which you fled from is very risky, and not a good idea at all.

That's because a refugee using the passport of the country from which the refugee has fled makes a statement that they now accept the authority of the country from which they've fled. This will be seen as ***abandoning their claim to refugee status***.

If the country that issued the refugee travel document learns of this use, it will likely cancel the refugee's travel document and the refugee's asylee status.